# How to get original Class type from Class object using ".class" in java?

Tags: java, class, casting

As part of an abstract generic API function, I include a parameter of type "Class" in the constructor which is used to deserialise a response (in JSON format) into an object of that class type.
Each API call can have a different response class.

Currently, my parent class definition is:

```
public MyRequest {

    private int method;
    private String url;
    private Class responseClass;
    
    private @Setter JSONObject params;

    public MyRequest(int method, String url, Class responseClass){
        this.method = method;
        this.url = url;
        this.responseClass = responseClass;
    }
    
    public void executeRequest(){
        new HttpJsonRequest(method,url,params) {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Object responseObj = new Gson().fromJson(String.valueOf(response), responseClass);
                onSuccess(responseObj);
            }
            ...
        }
    }
    
    public void onSuccess(Object response){}
    ...
}
```

An example API request that extends this:

```
public class ExampleRequest extends MyRequest {

    public ExampleRequest(String exampleParam){
        super(Request.Method.POST, "/example", MyResponse.class);
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        params.put("exampleParam",exampleParam);
        setParams(params);
        executeRequest();
    }
    
}
```

with basic response class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public MyResponse {
    private @Getter @Setter String StatusCode;
}
```

To use the above API class, I am overriding the onSuccess method which returns the Generic object and casting it back to the responseClass before proceeding, e.g.:

```
new ExampleRequest("exampleParamValue"){
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Object response){
        String StatusCode = ((MyResponse) response).getStatusCode(); 
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to amend MyRequest so that instead of responseObj being of class "Object", it can be of whatever class was passed into the constructor?
I'd like to avoid having to perform the cast from Object to this class in every onSucccess override I use.

Comment: Make `MyRequest` generic.

Comment: A lot of the code examples don't compile, so it makes it hard to fix the problem. In the future, please ensure that your code examples can be copied and compiled/run. It's helpful to also state your dependencies (or even better, rewrite the code to eliminate them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by making `MyRequest` generic, with a type parameter for the response type:

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MyRequest<R> {
    private int method;
    private String url;
    private Class<R> responseClass;

    private @Setter JSONObject params;

    public MyRequest(int method, String url, Class<R> responseClass) {
        this.method = method;
        this.url = url;
        this.responseClass = responseClass;
    }

    public void executeRequest() {
        new HttpJsonRequest(method, url, params) {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(JSONObject response) {
                R responseObj = new Gson().fromJson(String.valueOf(response), responseClass);
                onSuccess(responseObj);
            }
        };
    }

    public void onSuccess(R response) {
    }
}
```

Then, `ExampleRequest` would specify `MyResponse` as the value of the parameter:

```java
public class ExampleRequest extends MyRequest<MyResponse> {
   // ... no other changes
}
```

The cast is then no longer required when implementing `onSuccess`:

```java
new ExampleRequest("exampleParamValue"){
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(MyResponse response){
        String StatusCode = response.getStatusCode();
    }
};
```